# Making matplotlib plot nothing if input is not in domain

Tags: python, matplotlib

If you are making matplotlib plot a function whose domain is not all real numbers, for example `sqrt(x)`, how would you make it so that it plots the function over its domain, but doesn't plot the function at all when the input is not in the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have matplotlib show over the domain, just use [matplotlib.pyplot.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html). Here I use [numpy.linspace](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) to plot my function. The two first arguments are the boundaries of the domain. The last one is the number of samples to generate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10, num=100)
y = np.sqrt(x)
plt.xlim(-5, 20)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there an automated way to do this, instead of doing it manually by setting the limits, for example a function in a package/library that automatically gets the limits?

Comment: No, it is subjective. You have to decide which portion of the x axis you want to show, otherwise it'll be the default and the default doesn't extend out of the domain.